# Repository pattern with generic database context

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

In the generic repository described [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), a single database context `internal SchoolContext context;` is used. I want to build a generic repository but because I am using multiple databases (multiple connection strings), I do not want to hard code the database context. Is there a way of doing this that does not require re-writing the same methods for a different database context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make the context generic

Change the generic repository to look like that for example:

```cs
public class GenericRepository<TContext, TEntity>
    where TContext: DbContext
    where TEntity: class 
{
    internal TContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(TContext context) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

Now you can instantiate a repository for any kind of context.